# Check if a method is correct

Tags: java, arrays

I have a class with a method get done in this way:

```
public int get(int i) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if(i < numElements)
        return elements[i];
    else 
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("");
}
```

Now I have to make sure that this method works.
I do a test to test the get method on an array of length 0.
So in main I wrote:

```
    try {
      IntSortedArray r3 = new IntSortedArray(0); //I create an array of length 0
      if( **???** ) {
            System.out.println("OK");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("FAIL");
        }
    } catch(Exception ecc) {
        System.out.println(ecc + " FAIL");
    }
```

What do I put as a condition of the if? Thanks

---

The class IntSortedArray:

```
private int[] elements; 
private int numElements; 

public IntSortedArray(int initialCapacity) {
    elements = new int[initialCapacity];
    numElements = 0;
    System.out.println("Lunghezza dell'array: " + elements.length);
}
```

Comment: I doubt on this line `IntSortedArray r3 = new IntSortedArray(0); //I create an array of length 0` how to create an array?

Comment: what is the value of `numOfElements`? and can you check how to create an Array in Java on Google?

Comment: You haven't got an array anywhere.  An array would be declared something like `int[] myArray;` and allocated with something like `myArray = new int[100];`.

Comment: @HotLicks Licks I modified the main message

Comment: Why don't you use a real unit test framework like JUnit or TestNG. You shouldn't have to read what your code prints to know if tests pass or not.

Comment: @JBNizet - I suspect that using a test framework is beyond the OP's skill level at this point.  And there's no harm in learning how to create a testcase "from scratch".

Comment: @JBNizet Don't use JUnit because I'm not able to use it...

Comment: I'm sure you are. It's not very hard. You should ask a question telling what you tried and what didn't work. If you're serious about unit tests, you should definitely use a real unit test framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
try {
    IntSortedArray r3 = new IntSortedArray(0);
    r3.get(0);
    fail();
} catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException expected) {
}
```

Comment: Or, assuming this is JUnit code, simply annotate the method with `@Test(expected = ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class)`

Comment: @JBNizet This is is good if you have just one test, which is preferred.  However, if you have a longer method of tests, you can do the try/catch.

Comment: Agreed. If you want to test the exception message (or whatever else regarding the exception), this idiom is useful as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I did not want to use JUnit ... Is there another way to do it?

Comment: @user3425699 JUnit is one of the simplest and most popular.  You can run a main() for these tests if you want or write your own framework. There is also `testNG` testing framework, but for the most part it is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  So you've got at least two different things to test here:

- If the object can be constructed reasonably, and
- If you can retrieve an element from the object with respect to its size.

From that, given your constructor, you could construct your object with a non-negative number, as well as a negative number.  Further, you could also retrieve a non-negative element in bounds of your array, a non-negative element out of bounds to your array, and a negative element (which is definitely out of bounds) to your array.

There's about five test cases here.  I'll use JUnit as an example for you to test the case in which you're trying to pull an element out of your wrapped array, and it is out of bounds.  It will pass incidentally, since you're only doing one-half of the check; attempting to index into an array position that is equal to the length is also out of bounds.

```
// Test will pass due to exception being thrown.
@Test(expected = ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
public void getWithElementOutOfBounds() {
    IntSortedArray r3 = new IntSortedArray(0);
    rt.get(0);
}
```

With the `expected` portion of the `@Test` annotation, you can expect certain exceptions to be thrown without needing to provide a conditional, or a try-catch block.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I did not want to use JUnit ... Is there another way to do it?